# Query Associations in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Hi all I am using Spring Data Rest with a OneToMany relation. One Course has many students.

```
class Course { @OneToMany List<Student> students}

class Student {//No @ManyToOne relation}
```

Course is the owning entity. I'm attaching students to the class with PATCH or PUT. However now I want to find all Students that are not part of a Course. How do I do that. Since I do not have a BiDirectional Relationship. I cannot do findByCourseIsNull.

According to [How to maintain bi-directional relationships with Spring Data REST and JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464782/how-to-maintain-bi-directional-relationships-with-spring-data-rest-and-jpa) you should keep it unidirectional