# Spring data rest add element to collection

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to add an element to a @OneToMany relation following this [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) on Spring Data Rest, I'm using the request below to add an account to a user accounts collection.

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/account/1" http://localhost:8080/user/1/accounts
```

The request respond with a 204 and nothing changes when I check the user accounts list. Debugging the app I can see that the entity is being saved, so maybe a transaction commit is not happening. I also noticed that if I change the relation to a @OneToOne, the request works as expected.

> User class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "accounts")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sq", sequenceName = "user_sq")
public final class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "user_sq")
    private Long id;

    //other properties

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Account> accounts;

//    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    private Account accounts;
}
```

> Account class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "account_sq", sequenceName = "account_sq")
public final class Account extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "account_sq")
    private Long id;

    //other properties

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;    
}
```

> Repositories

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "accounts", path = "account")
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Comment: Could be a Lombok issue. Try manual setters and getters

Comment: This may be due to the fact the relationship is bi-directional. If you were doing this in code you would need to set both sides of the relationship to have the relationship cascade correctly. Can you try removing the back reference from Account to Owner to see if that affects the outcome? If that confirms the cause then see the explanation and possible workrounds here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464782/how-to-maintain-bi-directional-relationships-with-spring-data-rest-and-jpa

Comment: Thanks @AlanHay! The other post did the trick, the solution is a little weird, maybe I can find a better solution in the future (if there is any). Removing the bi-directional is an option for this case, but may not be in another future scenario and using @PreUpdate/@PrePersist doesn't feel right, I don't think I should need to use that (both solutions worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this body in your POSt or PUT/PATCH requests:

```
{
    // user properties...
    "accounts": [
            "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1",
            "http://localhost:8080/accounts/2"
        ]
}
```

To create new User (with his accounts) use POST request to http://localhost:8080/users

To update current User (and his accounts) use PUT/PATCH request to http://localhost:8080/users/1 (1 - is the ID of current user)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that your suggestion works, but that isn't within the scope of my question. I'm trying to understand/use what you can find in the documentation I linked in the question

Comment: This doesn't work anymore for me with Spring Boot 1.5.2 and Spring Data REST 2.6.1 and polymorphism.