# Spring Data Rest JPA OneToMany Null JoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, h2, spring-data-rest

Very simple one-to-many relationship - one human to many pets.

```
@Entity
class Human{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="human", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<Pet> pets;

  // other fields
}

@Entity
class Pet{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="human_id")
  private Human human;

  // others fields
}
```

This results in two tables created **HUMAN(id)** and **PET(id, human_id)**.

**EDIT-1**: I am using Spring Data Rest

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT-2**: Here is an updated look at how I am posting data.
And I'm posting to humans:

```
{
  // human data

  "pets": [
    "http://localhost/pets/1",
    "http://localhost/pets/2"
  ]
}
```

**Problem**: The **human_id** column in the the PET table **is null**. All the other fields are find but the relationship is not established.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain bi-directional relationships with Spring Data REST and JPA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464782/how-to-maintain-bi-directional-relationships-with-spring-data-rest-and-jpa)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the relationship persisted by removing mappedBy and putting the @JoinColumn along side the @OneToMany.

**Is there anything wrong with this? Performance issues?**

```
@Entity
class Human{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @JoinColumn(name="human_id")
  @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<Pet> pets;

  // other fields
}

@Entity
class Pet{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private Human human;

  // others fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using CascadeType.ALL in @ManyToOne column is dangerous.
It can delete a human when the pet is delete.

And,

Save haman after associate each object

```
Human human = new Human();
Pet pet1 = new Pet();
pet1.setHuman(human);
Pet pet2 = new Pet();
pet2.setHuman(human);

List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
pets.add(pet1);
pets.add(pet2);

human.setPets(pets);
```

And then save the `human`

Comment: Jaehyun, thanks but I'm using Spring Data Rest and I don't have control over setting the objects like this. It comes in through Jackson and straight to Hibernate.

Comment: @szxnyc Could you write your Post body?

Comment: I added the URL's that I'm using to post the pet relationship. I think you're looking to see that I'm using the URL's and not an actual pet definition.