# Dealing with m-to-n relations in @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

#### Preface

I want to create a sub-resource of another resource in *one* call. These resources have a `@ManyToMany` relationship: Users and Groups.

I **do not** want to create first a user, then the group and after that the relation as it is shown in [Working with Relationships in Spring Data REST](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) - simply because I think a resource that cannot exist on its own, such as a group, should only be created if at least *one* user is also associated with that resource. For this I require a single endpoint [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28081855/826983) (which is not working for me, otherwise I wouldn't be here) that creates a group and also sets the associated "seeding" user in one transaction.

Currently, the only way to make this work for me is to "synchronize" the relation manually like this:

```
public void setUsers(Set<AppUser> users) {
    users.forEach(u -> u.getGroups().add(this));
    this.users = users;
}
```

this would allow me to

```
POST http://localhost:8080/groups

{
  "name": "Group X",
  "users": ["http://localhost:8080/users/1"]
}
```

but my problem with that is that this does not feel right to me - it does seem like a workaround and not the actual Spring-way to make this requirement work. So ..

---

I'm currently struggling with creating relational resources using Spring's `@RepositoryRestResource`. I want to create a new group and associate it with the calling user like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/users/1/groups

{
  "name": "Group X"
}
```

but the only result is the response `204 No Content`. I have no idea why. This may or may not be related to another question of mine (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376620/creating-new-entity-plus-association-not-working)) where I try to achieve the same by setting the relating resource in the JSON payload - that doesn't work either.

Server side I am getting the following error:

```
tion$ResourceSupportHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>]]: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please let me know in case you need any specific code.

#### Tried

I added `exported = false` to the  `@RepositoryRestResource` of `UserGroupRepository`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "groups", path = "groups", exported = false)
public interface UserGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<UserGroup, Long> {
    List<UserGroup> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

and I am sending:

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/users/1

{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "Group X"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the result is still just `204 No Content` and a `ResourceNotFoundException` on the server side.

---

### Unit Test

Essentially, the following unit test is supposed to work but I can also live with an answer why this cannot work and which also shows how this is done correctly.

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate template;

private static String USERS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/users/";
private static String GROUPS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/groups/";

// ..

@Test
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public void whenCreateUserGroup() {

    // Creates a user
    whenCreateAppUser();

    ResponseEntity<AppUser> appUserResponse = template.getForEntity(USERS_ENDPOINT + "1/", AppUser.class);
    AppUser appUser = appUserResponse.getBody();

    UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup();
    userGroup.setName("Test Group");
    userGroup.setUsers(Collections.singleton(appUser));

    template.postForEntity(GROUPS_ENDPOINT, userGroup, UserGroup.class);

    ResponseEntity<UserGroup> userGroupResponse = template.getForEntity(GROUPS_ENDPOINT + "2/", UserGroup.class);

    Predicate<String> username = other -> appUser.getUsername().equals(other);

    assertNotNull("Response must not be null.", userGroupResponse.getBody());

    assertTrue("User was not associated with the group he created.",
            userGroupResponse.getBody().getUsers().stream()
                    .map(AppUser::getUsername).anyMatch(username));
}
```

However, the line

```
userGroup.setUsers(Collections.singleton(appUser));
```

will break this test and return a `404 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SDR reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_http_methods_3):

> POST
>
> Only supported for collection associations. Adds a new element to the collection. Supported media types:
>
> `text/uri-list` - URIs pointing to the resource to add to the association.

So to add `group` to `user` try to do this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/users/1/groups (with Content-Type:text/uri-list)
http://localhost:8080/groups/1
```

Additional [info](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships).

Comment: No, sorry but this is not what I want. I want to be able to create a new resource [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28081855/826983) and not having to issue another POST request from the client to the server that manages my relations in my database.

Comment: @displayname check my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198584 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302168

Comment: Hm, if I get this right the first example would create the group *and* the user. In my example the user already exists and only creates a new group. The second link has two example - the first one is the same and the second one does basically what your answer is currently proposing - or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: In my example an existing resource, the user, creates an entirely new resource (a group) and I don't want my client being in charge of creating the group *and* the relation. That should happen in one call on the server side.

Comment: @displayname in the case when you *already* have the 'parent' object and want to add to it a 'child' object you have to use 'PATCH' request (i.e. you are updating your 'parent'). Just do what I suggested in these answers but replace POST to PATCH. (But in common I think it's very bad idea to make 'groups' depended from  'user'...)

Comment: Hm, I've tried that now - see my updated question - but it's not doing anything except sending back `203 No Content` and a `ResourceNotFoundException` on the server side. Could you explain why this is a bad idea in general? How is it worse than making the client responsible for creating an association?

Comment: @displayname Are you sure that you created user1 before updating it? It's a bad idea because in real life users and groups are independent entities. So if you want to 'add' group to user you take reference to *already* existent group and link it with user. In this case ya can use approach from my answer.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now: I can either be able to create a new group using an existing user - this is when I set `exported = false` or I can do the other way: first create a group and after that associate the group with the user that *actually* created it. Am I getting that right? However, users and groups might be independent but only users should be able to create groups. My fear with the second solution is: What if a client creates a group and dies before it can associate that group with the user? Wouldn't that create row zombies?

Comment: @displayname I don't know anything about zombies ) But If you want to create object and link it with its author, in one time, you can use [event handler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler) to add user reference to group. But I think it's another question. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it help you...

Comment: Okay, sorry if I add another question regarding `@RepositoryEventHandler` - I am already using those but I didn't thought about using such a handler in order to manage a relation - I thought one only uses that to persist one model/entity. And yes, I think what I want to do here has to be performed in *one* transaction. By "zombie rows" I mean rows which are not associated with any other resource. E.g. a group without any users.

Comment: I'm trying to do it as you describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298596/spring-data-rest-status-500-for-entity-with-relation/47302168#47302168) (second part) but only the group gets created - not the user although having set `"users": ["http://localhost:8080/users/1"]`

Comment: @displayname check the last sentence of second part about synchronization of entities...

Comment: I could accept that if I knew that's really the way how to do it. I think this is something Spring JPA / Hibernate should take care of. Synchronizing the relation in the setter feels a bit like a hack.