# Insert cascade with @RepositoryRestResource, foreign key always null

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-rest

Maybe I am pushing my luck, but I am trying to implement a repository with `@RepositoryRestResource`, but the foreign key of the parent is not set in the child. I will try to explain what I did and what I found..

**First let's show what I did :**

UML :

[image: UML]

My Potato entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "POTATO")
public class PotatoEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "potato", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<DetailPotatoEntity> detailPotatoList;
}
```

My DetailPotato entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAIL_POTATO")
public class DetailPotatoEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "WEIGHT")
    private BigDecimal weight;

    @Column(name = "HEIGHT")
    private BigDecimal height;

    @JoinColumn(name = "POTATO_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference(value = "potato-detailPotato")
    private PotatoEntity potato;
}
```

My Potato repository :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "potatos", path = "potatos")
public interface PotatoRepository extends CrudRepository<PotatoEntity, BigInteger> {
}
```

The thing is that when I am pushing the following json :

```
{
    "firstname":"patate",
    "lastname":"potato",
    "detailPotatoList": [
            {
                "weight":12,
                "height":13
            }
        ]
}
```

the `POTATO_ID` in `DETAIL_POTATO` is always null. Normally, when you have your own controller et service, you would set the `PotatoEntity` in every `DetailPotatoEntity` and everything would have been alright. So, I would have tought that `@RepositoryRestResource` would have done it for me.. But it's not the case.

---

**How I "solved" it ? Or did I ?:**

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    detailPotatoList.forEach(detailPotato-> detailPotato.setPotato(this));
}
```

OR

```
public void setDetailPotatoList(List<DetailPotato> detailPotatoList) {
    detailPotatoList.forEach(detailPotato-> detailPotato.setPotato(this));
    this.detailPotatoList = detailPotatoList;
}
```

My question here is, is it normal that I have to do that ? Should `@RepositoryRestResource` suppose to manage that by its own ?

---

**Here is my observation :**

-Maybe `@RepositoryRestResource` should be use only for one entity only?

-I did a try with a DetailPotatoRepository just to see (in case you would check by your own, beware that you need to remove the `PotatoRepository` annoteted by `@RepositoryRestResource` to work):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "detailsPotato", path = "detailsPotato")
public interface DetailPotatoRepository extends CrudRepository<DetailPotatoEntity, BigInteger> {
}
```

and when I pushed the following json :

```
{
    "weight":12,
    "height":13,
    "potato": {
        "firstname":"pomme",
        "lastname":"apple"
    }
}
```

the `POTATO_ID` was set and everything was fine.

---

**Conclusion**

When the parent tells his children to persist, the children have no idea who is his parent. But, when the child tells his parent to persist, the child knows his parent.

Here again the question : Should `@RepositoryRestResource` suppose to manage that by its own ? Or `@RepositoryRestResource` should be use only for one entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a **bidirectional** association. In this case you should provide a [synchronization](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional-example) of your entities. Try to implement this in your `Potato#detailPotatoList` setter. Like this, for example:

```
public void setDetailPotatoList(List<DetailPotatoEntity> details) {
    if (detailPotatoList != null) {
        detailPotatoList.forEach(d -> d.setPotato(null));
    }
    if (details != null) {
        details.forEach(d -> d.setPotato(this));
    }
    detailPotatoList = details;
}
```

See my [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example2/Order.java).

Additional hint: [hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-easiest-way-to-manage-bi-directional-associations/)

Comment: I know that, that's why I have a section _how_ _I_ _"solved"_ _it_. My point is more about : should `@RepositoryRestResource` manage the bidirectional ? Because manually, I would have done what you did.

Comment: @GabLeg Unfortunately the SDR author [doesn't like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30474303) bidirectional associations.. (

Comment: That link was what I needed! I guess I wasn't searching with good words.. Thank you! :)